# PHP development server crashes after first request

Tags: php, server, crash, command-line-interface

The router script I'm using executes fully (an echo at the very end confirmed), but without the router script it is working fine. If I remove the run calls to my bootstrap script it also works fine. Somehow during execution of my website a condition is created that will make the server crash at the end. Error reporting and all that is on, so if there is an exception of any kind I should be able to see it.

Nothing is output to the console except the default PHP information.

```
$ php -S localhost:80 devrouter.php
PHP 7.0.11 Development Server started at Sat Oct  8 11:16:57 2016
Listening on http://localhost:80
Document root is ---
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
```

The status code returned is 9, but I could not find any reference on the development server's return codes.

I'm using PHP 7.0.11 with the thread-safe x64 Windows binary from php.net.

Answer (score 0):

By making the application exit at different points in execution I figured out the culprit is the Weakref extension. The act of simply using this extension at one point during execution is enough to make the next request that uses Weakref crash the server. I still have no solution for this yet, but I have submitted [an issue on Weakref's GitHub repository](https://github.com/colder/php-weakref/issues/28). I hope they will be able to solve it. In the meantime I'm leaving the use of Weakref out in my development environment.